# .OFF files on Python

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I've been practicing with Python and PyOpenGL, but I can't seem to open .OFF files ([Object File Format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_(file_format))) with Python.

If you're wondering, .OFF files are files that contain positions of a 3D object.

```
 OFF
 8 6 0
-0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
 0.500000 -0.500000 0.500000
-0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
 0.500000 0.500000 0.500000
-0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
 0.500000 0.500000 -0.500000
-0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
 0.500000 -0.500000 -0.500000
 4 0 1 3 2
 4 2 3 5 4
 4 4 5 7 6
 4 6 7 1 0
 4 1 7 5 3
 4 6 0 2 4
```

I want to read this file and make it appear on python.

The example should be like this:
http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/off/box.png

So far what I've had to do is write every coordinate from the .OFF file manually. But the program needs to be able to read every .OFF file you give it to.

I could only make the example I gave because I made a tuple of tuples for both the verticies and the surfaces:

```
verticiesCube = (
   (-0.5,-0.5,0.5),
   (0.5,-0.5,0.5),
   (-0.5,0.5,0.5),
   ...
   )
```

And

```
 surfacesCube = (
   (0,1,2,3),
   (2,3,5,4),
   (4,5,7,6),
   ...
   )
```

To then do:

```
 def Read(verticies,surfaces):
   glBegin(QL_QUADS)
   for surface in surfaces:
      for vertex in surface:
        glVertex3fv(verticies[vertex])
   glEnd()
```

Then I run Read(verticiesCube, surfacesCube) and a Cube appears.
My point is that you need to be able to do this with every .OFF file, and sometimes not all of them are equal (they have colors specified as well, or sometimes there are things written before the numbers so I don't know how to skip them. Example:)

```
  OFF
  #
  #  cone.off
  #
  22   40     120
  0.000000   1.000000   0.000000
  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000
  0.500000   0.000000   0.000000
```

(The #'s and the cone.off are the things I mentioned)

**So how do I save the coordinates and surfaces of the .OFF files into similar tuples so I can apply the Read() algorithm.**

Comment: Why did you delete your original question on this topic? I already gave you an answer there. Oh well, I'l just copy and paste my answer here, too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No idea on what the last field in the second line means. The rest can be deduced easily:

```
def read_off(file):
    if 'OFF' != file.readline().strip():
        raise('Not a valid OFF header')
    n_verts, n_faces, n_dontknow = tuple([int(s) for s in file.readline().strip().split(' ')])
    verts = [[float(s) for s in file.readline().strip().split(' ')] for i_vert in range(n_verts)]
    faces = [[int(s) for s in file.readline().strip().split(' ')][1:] for i_face in range(n_faces)]
    return verts, faces
```

Comment: Do you see the 4 at the start of every last line? How do I make it so it doesn't appear on the tuples?

Comment: @Kyle: Actually that '4' is telling you, what kind of geometrical primitive you're dealing with; kind of redundant, since that same information is also contained in the number of vertex indices referred to in that line. Anyway, dropping that first element is as simple as using Python slicing starting from the first element of the array (`…[1:]`) see my edit.

Comment: Thank you. Is it valid to write `raise Exception('Not a valid OFF header')` instead of `throw 'Not a valid OFF header`?

Comment: @Kyle: Perfectly valid. Although deriving a custom exception from `Exception` would be preferred. Also one may argue that the contents of the file are an invalid value and raise a `ValueError`.

Comment: Why is there a `n_dontknow` by the way?

Comment: @Kyle: Could have sliced away that field as well, but maybe that value gets important later on, and then by renaming the variable you already have it around.

Comment: By the way, in the example, the `8 6 0` part is not important since it's not an important part. Does the program take these numbers and create a tuple or are they excluded?

Comment: @Kyle: These numbers are vital for the program to work. That lines tells how many vertex and face lines to read. Without that information you could not reliable parse the whole thing. I suggest you carefully read and try to understand each and every statement in that snippet of Python code I gave you. I guess the hardest for you to wrap your head around are the so called "list comprehensions" in lines 4, 7 and 10

Comment: @Kyle: Exercise for you: Modify the reader to ignore lines starting with a `#`

Comment: Oh, now I understand. I was getting confused a bit, but now that I took my time reading it, it makes sense. Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: That'd be like in semi-code: `if line[0] == "#": pass to the next line`

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, and that would be the gist of what to do. Now the question is, how do you do it exactly, i.e. how do you get `line` and how to do that passing… I'll give you a hint: `continue`

Comment: Excuse me, how does the `int(s) for s in file.readline().strip().split(' ')` work? What if for example the line is `6 4 7`? And doesn't strip require a parameter?

Comment: @Kyle: It's a list comprehension (see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). If no parameter is given to strip, it clears of any kind of whitespace character from either end of the line.