# How to Construct Graph from .OFF python?

Tags: python

I have .off file ([OFF structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OFF_(file_format))) and I would like to construct a graph vertices and edges from this file.

I had found several libraries like networkX that may assist modeling 3d shapes to graph, but .off files are not supported. Each type of files have different format, like .obj differs in its format from .off.

And in all cases I prefer to do my own implementation.

I found the answer in this post ([.OFF files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129968/off-files-on-python)), but I wasn't able to get more clarification from the answer, especially I'm not experienced with python.

Comment: It was much easier than I thought, through trimesh library I was able to load the file, and then I was able to get vertices and faces, then the coordinates.Done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a library like `trimesh` to load the file. The vertices, faces and coordinates will be available.

There are other libraries that do this too: `vedo` `open3D` `py3dviewer`